# Counting Game Question, 2 players

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory, combinatorial-number-theory

Players A and B play the following game. Two integers, m and n, are written on the board. On each turn, a player selects one of the numbers on the board, erases it, and writes down a positive divisor of that number as long as it is different from any of the other numbers written on the board. For example, if 10 and 17 are written on the board, you can erase 10 and write 2 in it's place.

Suppose m = 2^40, n = 3^51. Assume that A goes first. Determine which player is always able to win the game, and explain the winning strategy.

My logic:

One can always write 1 as a divisor, as it divides both numbers and, in essence, is a legal move. Due to the restriction of only being able to write down a number if it is different from all the others, we can express the changing nature of the given numbers, m and n, as such:

if m = 2^40, you can write 2^39, 2^37, 2^34, and so on. The powers decrease by an increasing amount.

If we reduce each number, m and n, by this rule of decreasing powers, we end up with 2^4 and 3^6. Having used all previous divisors such as 2 and 3, we can no longer go on and the game pretty much ends there. Therefore, (16, 729) is a winning position, where 16 refers to the m value, and 729 refers to the n value.

I don't know where to go on from there. I would appreciate some help with this question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is an [impartial game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impartial_game), which means it is [Nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) in some disguise.  You have to discover how big the heaps are.  You have already found that for a prime power, $p^n$, the heap is of size $n-1$.  Now you have to think about how big a heap that has more than one prime factor is.  A good start is what is the maximum number of moves if the pile starts with $12=2^2\cdot 3$?

Comment: Would I have indirectly proved that Player A always wins though? The case you're talking about might refer to something else I think.

Comment: No, player A does not always win. The positions are divided into P positions, won by the previous player, and N positions, won by the next player. For example, 6 is a P position.  A can only move to 2 or 3, then B can move to 1 and win.

Comment: Being that it is a nim game in disguise, isn't the outcome of the game determined by the starting positions for both players?

Comment: Yes.  But the important point of Nim is that there is only one position, because both players can make the same moves in any given position.  Then the [Sprague-Grundy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem) applies

Comment: Yes, but if there's this one position, and player A goes first, it's possible to prove that one player will win every single time just because he goes first, and he has a certain type of advantage that makes the number game turn out to be the way it is.

Comment: No, that is not true as I demonstrated in the nxt to last comment. There are second player win positions. You are thinking that there is a "strategy stealing" proof, but that doesn't work here.  It can be a disadvantage to move, which invalidates the stealing argument.

Comment: I'm not seeing this.. could you show me in chat how?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the game.  If $m=4,n=9$ the second player wins.  A moves $4 \to 1, 9 \to 1, 4 \to 2,$ or $9 \to 3$ and B responds with $9 \to 3,4 \to 2, 9 \to 1,$ and $4 \to 1$ to win.